# how to bind an autocompletebox with a model in mvvm?

Tags: mvvm, wpftoolkit

i exposed a collection and binded it to itemsource of autocompletebox which works but selecting or changing the text on the autocompletebox doesn't update the model like a textbox or a label!

viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<String> SymptomsDb { get; private set; }

private String symptom;

public String Symptom
{
    get { return symptom; }
    set
    {
        symptom = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Symptom);
    }
}

public AnalysisViewModel()
{
    List<String> s = new List<String>();
    s.Add("test");
    SymptomsDb = new ObservableCollection<String>(s);
}
```

view:

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomsDb}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Symptom}" 
    Text="{Binding Symptom}" 
    IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" 
    FilterMode="Contains"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a change from the user interface back to the viewmodel, you will always need to bind the property TwoWay (except some properties like TextBox.TextProperty that are TwoWay by [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx)):

```
<controls:AutoCompleteBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomsDb}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Symptom, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Text="{Binding Symptom}" 
    IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" 
    FilterMode="Contains"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I lost hours trying to understand why the control will not bind Text property correctly to IDataErrorInfo class.